# Foreman ignores default port in .foreman file

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

I have a NodeJs application deployed on Heroku.

Since I need to execute to different Procfile in production and development I have installed Foreman for Node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreman).

After that I created my .env file and .foreman file and my two Procfile: Profile and Procfile.dev

Executing the command to start the server

```
nf start -f Procfile.dev
```

Throws the following error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE Procfile.dev
```

That's because Foreman by default select the port 5000.
So I inserted this code in the .foreman file:

```
port: 3003
```

The problem is that option is still ignored and I still receive the EADDRINUSE error. Even executing the command:

```
nf start -p 3003 -f Procfile.dev
```

solve anything, the port is still ignored.

On the other site if I execute command without the -f flag, the port option is not ignored.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On Heroku, you can't specify what port you want to bind to -- Heroku will tell you what port you can use.

Heroku does this by creating an environment variable for you called `PORT`.

So, in order to make your web server work, you need to have foreman start your web server on the port specified in the `PORT` environment variable.